# PyQt5 Display Issue

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

I've asked pretty much the same question here before (I've since deleted it after getting no solutions), but one peculiarity has arose since then.

The following program:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('Test')
w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

does **not** produce a window, generates no errors, and continues to run until forcefully terminated. However, the same code **does** produce a window in the interactive interpreter.

I have repaired python; uninstalled, reinstalled, upgraded, and downgraded both python and PyQt including PyQt's other versions, as well as the dependencies any PyQt version requires. I am at a total loss as to what/where the problem is, especially since PyQt5 had worked properly before on the same machine.

*Any* help in fixing this would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc Windows.

Comment: Could you explain how you have installed pyqt.

Comment: @eyllanesc pip.

Comment: What version of python do you have?

Comment: @eyllanesc 3.6 and 3.5

Comment: And in which of them you have installed pyqt, try using only a version of python and reinstall pyqt in that version.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, as stated in the post.

Comment: What is the python that you have placed the path in the environment variables? I think there may be conflict between dlls.

Comment: @eyllanesc Just 3.6, I have removed 3.5 from them already.

Comment: You could explain how you run the application. You use some ide, or execute it through the CMD.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sublime Text 3

Comment: Try to run it from the cmd, for example: `python.exe path_of_your_script`